# Convergence of series with modified denominator

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, contest-math

Suppose the series with positive terms $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges. Let $r_n=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}a_k$.

Prove or disprove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{r_n}$ diverges,

and prove or disprove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{r_n}}$ converges.

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.SE. Since you are new, I want to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many users find the use of the imperative ("prove", etc.) to be rude when asking for help. Please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 2):

1. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n/r_n$ must diverge. For all $k$ and $\ell>k$,
   $$\sum_{k\le n\le \ell} \frac{a_n}{r_n}\ge
   \sum_{k\le n\le \ell} \frac{a_n}{r_k}= \frac{a_k+a_{k+1}+\dots+a_{\ell}}{a_k+a_{k+1}+\dots}.
   $$
   The limit of the right-hand side as $\ell\to\infty$ is $1$, so for any $k$ we can choose $\ell>k$ such that
   $$
   \sum_{k\le n\le \ell} \frac{a_n}{r_n}>\frac12.
   $$
   Therefore, the sum $\sum_n a_n/r_n$ must diverge.
2. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n/\sqrt{r_n}$ must converge.  The partial sum $\sum_{1\le n\le \ell} \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{r_n}}$ can be rewritten as
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   \sum_{1\le n\le \ell} \frac{r_n-r_{n+1}}{\sqrt{r_n}}
   &\le&
   \sum_{1\le n\le \ell} \ \int_{r_{n+1}}^{r_n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx\\
   &=& \int^{r_1}_{r_{\ell+1}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx\\
   &\le& \int_0^{r_1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx\\
   &=& 2\sqrt{r_1}.
   \end{eqnarray*}
   Therefore, the sum $\sum_n a_n/\sqrt{r_n}$ has bounded partial sums, and it is a sum of positive terms, so it converges.  The same method of proof could be used to show that $\sum_n a_n \phi(r_n)$ converges for any positive function $\phi$ such that, for some $\epsilon>0$, $\phi$ is decreasing on $(0,\epsilon]$ and $\int_0^\epsilon \phi(x) \, dx <+\infty$.